# Discord.py sudo all command not responding

Tags: python, discord.py

This might need a little explaining. I made a command that sudo's someone called `p!sudo [member.mention] [message]`. It works like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def sudo(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
    for webhook in webhooks:
        await webhook.delete()
    webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
    await webhook.send(str(message),
                       username=member.name,
                       avatar_url=member.avatar_url)
```

Now, I want to make another command that sudo's everyone in the server. Here's what I got:

```py
@client.command()
async def sudoall(ctx, *, message=None):
  for member in ctx.guild.member:
    webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
    for webhook in webhooks:
        await webhook.delete()
    webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
    await webhook.send(str(message),
                       username=member.name,
                       avatar_url=member.avatar_url)
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Ignoring exception in command sudoall:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 34, in sudoall
    for member in ctx.guild.member:
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'member'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'member'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ctx.guild.members`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.6.0/discord/guild.py#L514) to get the list of members belonging in a guild